# In ASP.net chart, how can I add label on the basis of value from the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have the following table containing two columns. I am making a bar chart. My question is how can I add xDate column values as label instead of specifying interval = 7 etc, which is auto labeled by chart tool.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771768/line-up-x-axis-labels-with-chart-columns-asp-net-chart-control). Add IsXValueIndexed="true" to the series and Interval="1". It will get the labels from the table (in my case xDate).